# Fixing TextView background issue

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/text_box_middle_imanage" >

<TextView android:text="header text here" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


<TextView android:text="large content Text here" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I want to set a single background to a number of textViews. So i put all the text Views in a linearLayout and add background in this linear layout. There is a heading text and some content text which is organized into multiple TextViews. The Problem i am facing is: When i put large text in 2nd textView it is expanding the layout but i want that the background image should be fixed should not expand on adding text. And all the text Should reside into the background bounds only. I know this is not much tricky but I am new to android so facing this problem.

I know one way to give fixed width(in px or dp) to the linear layout but it would not be a good approach (if I am correct). Is there any other way?

here is the screen shot you can figure out the problem by this: http://postimage.org/image/1a8d1g538/

Comment: You want to have background image to each TextView or a single background and on that you overlap all TextView ?

Comment: yea a single background and on that you overlap all TextViews.

Comment: can you put some sample screen shot ?

Comment: @Chirag i have added the screen shot please have a look what i want

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/contentLayout" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/untitled" >

    <TextView 
        android:text="header text here" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <TextView 
       android:text="large content Text here" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have given android:layout_width="fill_parent" which make the layout take the complete width of the screen but as in my question i want the width to be exactly of the back ground image size please have a look on the screen shot

Comment: Can you please upload only image that you want in background..And I dont see any alignment and paragraph settings on text overlapping on image

Comment: please ignore the red background with boy and girl. Please consider the weight shaded image which is in the background of text.

Comment: I can see two white images. Which you going to use ?

Comment: actually there are 3 white images: 1 top and 1 in bottom of LinearLyout(which contain all the text). and one is in the background of of linearlayout. All my text content is going to reside in this layout. See carefully the middle part is expanding it has a image in the background.

Comment: Can you please upload your linearlayout background image file ?

Comment: Adding that image wont make any difference man. Instead of using white colored image, set backgroundColor of linearlayout to white. And set text color to Black...

Comment: hye !! please see the image carefully http://postimage.org/image/21nex3pxg/ There are shades on the right and left side it gives a different look when inserted with top and bottom part http://postimage.org/image/1a8d1g538/

Comment: Its displaying text with white background. i dont see any shades there